# D3 Graph Not Appearing in Div

Tags: javascript, html, css, d3.js

Despite copying the code straight out of one of my previously working programs (It still works).That one is also located in a div, but in a single one. Then when I put it into program full of divs, it doesn't work. Here is what it looks like in the original: [image]

What the result is when I try to copy it over (top left):[image]

Link and source for each: [Individual Graph](https://secure.scheduleinterpreter.com/bestinterpreters/wip/dashboard/ada/noob/tgraph.html), [Cards](https://secure.scheduleinterpreter.com/bestinterpreters/wip/dashboard/ada/Dashboard/dashboard.005.html)

What I'm asking is (A) What am I doing wrong and (B) how do I fix it.

Comment: Turn on your console. You will see several errors due to NaN values (which should be numbers). Try printing some of the data (console.log) before generating the graphs. It might give you a clue on where the data is going. Or try to isolate your problem in a JSFiddle. It will be easier to help (and you might discover the problem yourself)

Comment: I noticed that. I'll take a look. Thanks @helderdarocha

Comment: one issue is that style.getPropertyValue('width') includes the px suffix. And so when you try to add that to the margin.left + margin.right it's doing string concatenation instead of addition.

Comment: @Zeph Believe it or not, I just figured that out. Thanks a bunch for the help

Comment: Second thing - the svg selection should be d3.selectAll(".front") instead of d3.select("#front") to get all the divs.